# Apache commons-logging bridge for log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to set up log4j2 for Apache Commons Logging using the *commons-logging.properties* file. For Log4j 1 I could use `org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger` which maps to version Log4j 1.2. I couldn't find out the implementation for log4J2. The version I am using is 2.8.2.

The Log4J2 documentation for [Log4J Commons Logging Bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.3/log4j-jcl/index.html) specifies that by just ***adding the bridge jar along with the other Log4j 2 jars and the Commons Logging jar, all logging done using the Commons Logging API will be routed to Log4***. I tried this by adding

- log4j-api
- log4j-core
- log4j-jcl
- commons-logging

dependencies in the *pom.xml* without using the *commons-logging.properties* but didn't work that way.
How can I implement this with or without the commons-logging.properties?

**[UPDATE]**

*Not sure if this has an impact on the issue but updating in spite of it*. I debugged the commons-logging source code and found in `LogFactoryImpl.java` it looks for a logging implementation ([L843](https://github.com/apache/commons-logging/blob/LOGGING_1_2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.java#L843)) from a list ([L162](https://github.com/apache/commons-logging/blob/LOGGING_1_2/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl.java#L162)). Here since the Log4JLogger does not support Log4J2 it then sets to the next in line, that is JDK14Logger. Since the Log4J2 documentaiton says adding the bridge simply maps the logs from JCL to Log4J2, what role does the bridging api play here? I noticed the `LogFactoryImpl.java` and `Log4JLog.java` in it but how does commons-logging refer to these which are in a different package?

Comment: As far as I know, no _commons-logging.properties_ file is required. You mention you tried but it didn't work. Can you be more specific? Was there an error message, or simply nothing happens? Can you show a small example application that reproduces the problem?

Comment: There is no error message popping up but rather the commons-logging gets bridged to JDK14Logger. But the console does not log anything.

Comment: @RemkoPopma Showing a sample is quite a workaround. What happens is there is a central logging component which is referred by other components and this component has the dependencies to the above four and exports log4j2 and commons-logging bundled in it.

Comment: Would you mind asking on the Log4j2 user mailing list?